# InitDevice::CreateDevice problems with wine

Tags: wine, games

I have a game on my Sony Vaio (Pirates of the Caribbean). Whenever I try to run it under Wine, I get the following error message:

> InitDevice::CreateDevice The device does not support the queried technique.

What does this mean and if so how may I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [virtual desktop](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/config-wine-main), it is in Graphics tab of "winecfg".